# Process path does not exists

Tags: linux, process, virus

A VM of mine got infected with some crypto mining malware. I can kill it but it obviously restart at each boot. I tried finding the executable but I can't get my hands on it; the process path (from `htop`, `ls -l`, `lsof -p`, ect) does not exists.
How is this possible and how can I find the executable and delete it ?

Here are some outputs to prove waht I'm saying.

```
root@mediaserver:/home/tech#  ls -l /proc/3648/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 media media 0 juin  23 00:48 /proc/3648/exe -> /config/c3pool/xmrig
root@mediaserver:/home/tech# readlink /proc/3648/exe
/config/c3pool/xmrig
root@mediaserver:/home/tech# lsof  -p 3648
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
xmrig   3648 media  cwd       DIR   0,82     4096 20054344 /
xmrig   3648 media  rtd       DIR   0,82     4096 20054344 /
xmrig   3648 media  txt       REG  254,2  2364488 22675798 /config/c3pool/xmrig
xmrig   3648 media  mem       REG  254,2          13503512 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris (path inode=31594143)
xmrig   3648 media    0r      CHR    1,3      0t0   101092 /dev/null
xmrig   3648 media    1w      CHR    1,3      0t0   101092 /dev/null
xmrig   3648 media    2w      CHR    1,3      0t0   101092 /dev/null
xmrig   3648 media    3r      CHR    1,9      0t0   101097 /dev/urandom
xmrig   3648 media    4u  a_inode   0,13        0    10340 [eventpoll]
xmrig   3648 media    5r     FIFO   0,12      0t0   231408 pipe
xmrig   3648 media    6w     FIFO   0,12      0t0   231408 pipe
xmrig   3648 media    7r     FIFO   0,12      0t0   238200 pipe
xmrig   3648 media    8w     FIFO   0,12      0t0   238200 pipe
xmrig   3648 media    9u  a_inode   0,13        0    10340 [eventfd]
xmrig   3648 media   10w      REG  254,2 87499703 22675799 /config/c3pool/xmrig.log
xmrig   3648 media   11u  a_inode   0,13        0    10340 [eventfd]
xmrig   3648 media   12u     sock    0,9      0t0   231410 protocol: UNIX
xmrig   3648 media   13u  a_inode   0,13        0    10340 [eventfd]
xmrig   3648 media   14r  a_inode   0,13        0    10340 inotify
xmrig   3648 media   15r      CHR    1,3      0t0   101092 /dev/null
xmrig   3648 media   16u     sock    0,9      0t0   243829 protocol: TCP
root@mediaserver:/home/tech# cd /config
bash: cd: /config: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

EDIT: With the help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time I managed to find the origins. He installed is malware at multiple places and when he runs it he checks here is not already a process existing.
I'm gonna let the grep finish and will delete all the copy of it. But I still wonder how the script are executed... Is someone has an idea; below are some logs to better understand the situation:

```
root@mediaserver:/home/tech# sudo time grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var,/shares} '/' -e 'xmrig'
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/code-server/c3pool/config.json:63:    "log-file": "/config/c3pool/xmrig.log",
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/code-server/c3pool/config_background.json:90:    "log-file": "/config/c3pool/xmrig.log",
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/code-server/c3pool/miner.sh:2:if ! pidof xmrig >/dev/null; then
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/code-server/c3pool/miner.sh:3:  nice /config/c3pool/xmrig $*
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/code-server/c3pool/miner.sh:6:  echo "Run \"killall xmrig\" or \"sudo killall xmrig\" if you want to remove background miner first."
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/config.json:65:    "log-file": "/config/c3pool/xmrig.log",
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/config_background.json:112:    "log-file": "/config/c3pool/xmrig.log",
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/miner.sh:2:if ! pidof xmrig >/dev/null; then
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/miner.sh:3:  nice /config/c3pool/xmrig $*
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/miner.sh:6:  echo "Run \"killall xmrig\" or \"sudo killall xmrig\" if you want to remove background miner first."
/shares/backup/mediaserver/delta_9/config/qbittorrent/c3pool/miner.sh:8:  echo "如果要先删除后台矿工，请运行 \"killall xmrig\" 或 \"sudo killall xmrig\"."
```

```
media@mediaserver:~$ ls -al /appdata/config/code-server/c3pool/
total 87800
drwxr-xr-x  2 media media     4096 déc.  31  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 media media     4096 janv.  6 12:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 media media     4172 déc.  31  2020 config_background.json
-rw-r--r--  1 media media     2441 déc.  31  2020 config.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 media media      277 déc.  31  2020 miner.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 media media  2364488 déc.  23  2020 xmrig
-rw-r--r--  1 media media 87510988 juin  23 02:46 xmrig.log

media@mediaserver:~$ cat /appdata/config/code-server/c3pool/miner.sh 
#!/bin/bash
if ! pidof xmrig >/dev/null; then
  nice /config/c3pool/xmrig $*
else
  echo "Monero miner is already running in the background. Refusing to run another one."
  echo "Run \"killall xmrig\" or \"sudo killall xmrig\" if you want to remove background miner first."
fi
```

Comment: if you can confirm infection by anything more than the simplest of malware, seriously consider backing up your content files and rebuilding the box. there's just no way you can ever trust it again.

Comment: Everything is backed up, but a full reinstall would take a week probably to make sure everything works fine. If I can solve this one problem in a night I would gladly take it even tho I can't trust the box.

Comment: Like other files the exe file once opened can be unlinked to remove the directory entry(s) but the inode and content continues to exist until closed by the(all) using process(es) (which your malware process won't). The bogus exe is probably being created only momentarily by something hidden elsewhere and deleted after it is used to run the malware process, so it doesn't exist statically and you can't find it. Looking for the parent process _might_ help but if the attacker is any good they also make that useless.

Comment: They gained acces vi an unsecure user password over ssh. Big mistake but passwd changed and ssh not forwarded on my router now. This user is not sudoer and other users have very strong passwd.
Assuming he gained access to only one user and cannot has acces to it anymore; can I also assume that by deleting that user then the script creating the bogus exe won't be able to run ?
Also there must be some cron or scheduled task to run (bogus start 15/20min after boot; does not restart on kill after hours); how could one locate such a cron/task ? (nothing in crontabs currently)